# NullPointerException при работе с StackExchangeApi

Tags: java, stackoverflow-api

Вообщем зарегестрировал приложение в **stackapps** и получил Key. Далее нашел пример и попробовал его запустить, но ловлю ошибку, кто то может подсказать в чем проблема? или показать годный туториал по использованию **StackExchangeApi**

Вот код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StackExchangeApiClientFactory factory = StackExchangeApiClientFactory.newInstance("dybйjLCjoйй0BA*g*rMYyDA((");
        StackExchangeApiClient client = factory.createStackExchangeApiClient();
        List<Question> questions = client.getQuestions(Question.SortOrder.HOT, new Paging(1, 20), new TimePeriod(new Date(), new Date()), EnumSet.of(FilterOption.INCLUDE_BODY, FilterOption.INCLUDE_COMMENTS));
        for (Question q : questions) {
            System.out.println(q.getBody());
        }

    }
}
```

и стектрейс ошибки:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.code.stackexchange.client.impl.StackExchangeApiGateway.callApiMethod(StackExchangeApiGateway.java:269)
    at com.google.code.stackexchange.client.impl.StackExchangeApiGateway.callApiMethod(StackExchangeApiGateway.java:233)
    at com.google.code.stackexchange.client.impl.BaseStackExchangeApiClient.getQuestions(BaseStackExchangeApiClient.java:288)
    at Main.main(Main.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

после смены старой либы на новую выдает:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.code.stackexchange.client.query.impl.BaseStackOverflowApiQuery.<clinit>(BaseStackOverflowApiQuery.java:84)
    at com.google.code.stackexchange.client.query.StackExchangeApiQueryFactory.newQuestionApiQuery(StackExchangeApiQueryFactory.java:179)
    at Main.callStackExchange(Main.java:90)


[INFO] StackExchange API Java SDK ......................... SUCCESS [  1.747 s]
[INFO] stackexchange-java-schema .......................... SUCCESS [  5.533 s]
[INFO] stackexchange-java-core ............................ FAILURE [01:30 min]
[INFO] stackoverflow-java-sdk-release ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:37 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-03T17:39:21+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/347M
```

Comment: Какая версия библиотеки/откуда скачивали?

Comment: качал отсюда https://code.google.com/archive/p/stackoverflow-java-sdk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, вы используете устаревшую библиотеку. StackExchange сменил API на версию 2, попробуйте [вот эту](https://github.com/sanjivsingh/stackoverflow-java-sdk) библиотеку.

Comment: подключил новую библиотеку но падает теперь с другой ошибкой добавил в вопрос

Comment: @KirillStoianov Библиотеку вы собрали в соответствии и инструкциями? Через мавен или включив 3 джарника в classpath?

Comment: поключил как модуль, при попытке сборки мавеном получал ошибку, добавил в впорос